# remove an item from a list in a matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, indexing, del

I've got a problem. I'm trying to remove an item from a list, inside a matrix, but when I try to remove that item from a specific list (es. matrix[0]) it remove that item from every list inside the matrix.

Here's the code:

```
ap = 95
sp = [125, 150]
ch = 195
sett = []
giorno = []
for matt in range(ap,sp[0]+5,5):
    giorno.append(matt)
for sera in range(sp[1],ch+5,5):
    giorno.append(sera)

for i in range(5):
    sett.append(giorno)

print(sett[1])
for i  in range(0,5,2):
        del sett[i][0]
print(sett[1])
```

Output:

```
1st printf(sett[1]):
[95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195]
2nd printf(sett[1]):
[110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195]
```

Expected Output

```
1st printf(sett[1]):
[95, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195]
2nd printf(sett[1]):
[95, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195]
```

Please Help Me!

Comment: What's the input and what's the expected output?

Comment: No, it does not. It removes the first item in rows [0, 2, 4].

Comment: Please explain in detail given input and expected output.

Comment: The input is up here, it should remove the first item in rows [0, 2, 4], but it doesn't. it do it to every row.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add code how you create this matrix as well.

Comment: sorry for everything, I'm new here

Comment: @DoubleS04 - welcome to SO. To answer your question, we need two main things: (1) the original data (matrix, before you executed your code), and (2) the expected output. That is - what do you *want* the result to be.

Comment: Since all the rows in the matrix are the same, can't you just do sett[0:2] ?

Comment: I need to modify the first, the third and the fifth row (index(0,2,4)). The second end the fourth have to remain the same as before

Comment: He means that the matrix itself removes elements from lists which should not. From his loop to delete elements, the list should remove only the first element from the lists with index 0, 2 and 4. But it removes the first element from all elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `del` to delete an element you could use list slicing to set the rows in the matrix to a slice of the original rows minus the first element. This can be done like so:

```
for i in range(0,5,2):
    matrix[i] = matrix[i][1:]

print(matrix)
```

This gives the result

```
[[100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195], 
[95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195], 
[100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195], 
[95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195], 
[100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195]]
```

Whereby in rows 0, 2 and 4 the first elements are deleted. This could also be shortened using list comprehension to:

```
matrix = [row[1:] if i % 2 == 0 else row for i, row in enumerate(matrix)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you do not create a shallow copy of the list.
I don't know how Python shares memory and pointers, but I can say that if you copy the `giorno` list in-memory, instead of appending it directly multiple times, it should work. Probably it's because Python, when editing a single list, edits also the other references of the list.

Try shallow copying it by reinstantiating it:

```py
for i in range(5):
    sett.append(list(giorno))
```

or by slicing it in a null way:

```py
for i in range(5):
    sett.append(giorno[:])
```

And then it should work as expected.

Also, if you want to remove the first 5 elements from a list, you shouldn't loop through it, because the elements will get removed while looping, and it would remove incorrect elements.
So, just delete elements by doing

```py
del sett[i][0]
```

and you'll remove the first 5 elements as expected.